# fix error : Value '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native

Whenever i'm trying to run my react native application with this command `react-native run-android` getting this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Value '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan 
to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

My Paths in environment variables are correct and are as follows :

System variables -
***JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin***

I even tried to change a line in `/android/gradle.properties` as -

1. `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home`
2. `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. `org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281`

BUT NONE OF THE ABOVE ARE WORKING

on opening android folder in Android Studio, getting same error - Value `'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)`

***Please help me***

Comment: que: 1. what OS are you working on (you seem to mix both macOS & Windows paths) ? 2. is java installed on your machine ? where did you install JDK ?

Comment: it's windows :) btw I've fixed it . Thank you so much

Comment: @ShoubhikRaj How did you fix it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the mentioned line in gradle.properties
It is the JDK path for macOS and do not support Windows OS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).